# Why define factory function for records?

Tags: clojurescript

In swannodettes clojurescript tutorial (https://github.com/swannodette/lt-cljs-tutorial/blob/master/lt-cljs-tutorial.cljs), it's claimed that:

**It's considered idiomatic (and recommended) to define a factory function
 which returns the created instance of a defrecord/deftype. It's idiomatic to use
 dash-case for factories names.**

With the example:

```
(defn person [first last]
  (->Person first last))
```

Why?

The only thing i can think of is if you're using one set of parameters and they don't match the implementation, either as a transformation:

```
(defn person [full-name]
  (->Person (first (split full-name)) ... ))
```

Or as a guard against changing implementation when used as a library.

Is that it?

The downsides would be extra, unneccesary functions, that needs to be updated in paralell with the implementations, and perhaps slightly more unclear names.

I don't like boilerplate code, so I'm always frustrated when given such recommendations without explanations.

Comment: http://stuartsierra.com/2015/05/17/clojure-record-constructors

Answer (score 1):

Java allows for multiple constructors with different signatures IE

```
public class Foo implements Bar {
    private final Boolean initialState;
    public Foo () { this.initialState = false; }    
    public Foo (Boolean initialState) { this.initialState = initialState; }
    public void sayState () {System.out.println(this.initialState)}
}
```

Clojure constructors cannot be customised in this way. You basically get a single constructor created for you, based on the fields vector supplied to `defrecord`.

```
(defrecord Foo [initial-state] Bar (sayState [this] (println initial-state)))
```

So, if you want to construct an object based on a signature that doesn't match the fields vector of `defrecord` you will need a wrapper fn to set the default value of initial-state.

And if the fields vector of `defrecord` ever changes, the factory method will future proof you against having to change all the occurrences of `(->Foo state)` in your code.

Comment: You get two constructors; `->Record` & `map->Record`.

Comment: I didn't know about that map-> constructor. That's quite cool. I don't think it detracts from my answer though, if you want to initialize objects with default vaues other than nil you will still need a "factory" fn.

Answer (score 1):

> Or as a guard against changing implementation when used as a library.
>
> Is that it?

I think that's it.

If your records are for internal use, just using one of the supplied constructors can be the most straightforward thing to do. Perhaps you have prototyped using maps and have realized you need records for some reason. So there is (probably) no going back, `->Record` & `map->Record` would be fine.

But when you are providing an API for others it should be as **stable** as possible. You don't want to surprise the consumers and have them perform large refactorings. At the very least, by providing a custom constructor you can produce clear deprecation warnings.

I usually consider `->Record` & `map->Record` constructors implementation details and hide them.

**TL;DR:** It's a different story when you are writing code by yourself, for yourself and another story when you are writing a library that will potentially be used by a thousand others.